# Can't resolve javax.servlet.http

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I used to create web application in eclipse and I never got this issue.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
The import javax.servlet.http cannot be resolved
```

I was working on a project just the last week with no problem but when I add new project the `HttpServletRequest` cannot be resolved !!

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+O . if using eclipse.
or add javax.servlet jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have servlet-api.jar in your classpath in order to reslove this.
however it is usually provided by the servlet container.
In eclipse, make sure that the project is a 'Dynamic Web Project', then you have server installed in eclipse, and then the server is selected as a 'targeted runtime' for that project.

Comment: I select the apache tomcat in 'targeted runtime' and it' works :) thanks @tariqkhan, but why in other projects the server in 'targeted runtime' was already selected ?

Comment: it may happen due to many reasons, like if you added the server after you created the project, or if the project you are working on was imported into the work-space, or u didn't select the option of 'Dynamic Web Project' when initially creating the project etc etc.
Anyways now that is resolved, I am glad that i could help.
-happy coding

Answer (score 1):

[image]Assign `Web App Libraries` and `server Runtime` library  in project build path

Comment: If you have already added then remove it and add it again. It could be because you have changed your container(tomcat) server path.

Comment: I select the apache tomcat in 'targeted runtime' and it' works :) no need of web App Libraries in my case because this library was empty.

Comment: Great, I've suggested web app libraries because if you have imported this project again than eclipse will not include the same.